# fb graph api response not returning friends who made a log in to custom app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created an android app & same in facebook.
I am able to login in FB and others also from android app.

But while querying the friends in graph api tool by keeping my app as application, I am not getting friends ID who accepted my app and made a log in.

So here what else is required to get friends also in the graph api call.

TIA.

Comment: You requested `user_friends` permission?

Comment: Hi, Yes. I checked the pick list in get access token.